# MySQL on Ubuntu 1500% slower than on a less powerful Mac, what might be wrong?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, mac-osx

I have a very fast 8 core Ubuntu 10.10 64 bit desktop machine with 16GB of memory running MySQL 5.1.41 but something seems to be wrong with the MySQL installation (even though it's an unmodified stock MySQL installation). I also have a less powerful dual-core Mac Mini running Snow Leopard 10.7 and MySQL 5.0.91.

When loading loading a small 9MB mysqldump generated database the Ubuntu machine takes 33 seconds of wall time and the Mac mini takes 2 seconds:

ubuntu> time mysql --user=root vm-dev -e "source test/database/database.sql"
real    0m33.554s
user    0m0.220s
sys 0m0.030s

macmini> time mysql --user=root vm-dev -e "source test/database/database.sql"
real    0m2.077s
user    0m0.108s
sys 0m0.054s

What kinds of things should I look for that could be wrong with the ubuntu server?

Comment: what version is the MySQL *client* on Ubuntu?

Comment: 5.1.41, can't believe I left that detail out...

Comment: how many times did you run the test?

Comment: I've run the test about 30 times now while running top and iotop to verify that nothing else is running on the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't exactly overwhelmed us with relevant details but considering the huge difference in performance I believe you have a screwed installation. I suggest removing MySQL from the Ubuntu machine, along with any and all related files, rebooting it and reinstalling from scratch.

Comment: Hi John, what other kinds of details should I include for future reference? Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @ToddH, in general the more information the better. e.g. CPU speed,  table types (are they the same in both cases?) types of queries (simple, complex, joins, unions, etc. but of course that doesn't really matter if the exact same queries are run on both systems and they both use the same table types) and finally, the most important of all, the configurations of the systems. Quite often performance issues can be tracked back to just one or two differences in the configs.